# Sharepoint DateTimeControl: set it to null

Tags: sharepoint, datetime

how can I set the selected value of a Sharepoint DateTimeControl to null? When you first load it into a page, there's no value selected (even if the returned value is not properly null but one can check it with IsDateEmpty). How can i programmatically set it back to the initial, empty value?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Found it.

```
myDateTimeControl.ClearSelection();
```